# Issues with WiFi on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, internet, streaming, wifi-driver

I have a strange issue on Windows 10. When I am watching YouTube videos (or any other streaming sites) the first 4-5 minutes load fine and then the WiFi sort of goes into a "sleep" mode and won't respond. The video starts buffering with the loading symbol going round and round. I just figured out that when I tap the WiFi icon in the taskbar, the WiFi is back to its senses and starts streaming for the next 4-5 minutes after which the same thing repeats. However, downloads, of any size, go through just fine. I have tried messing around with power options that may potentially be the cause of the problem with no luck. For example, in the power options, I have set WiFi to maximum performance and disabled "let the PC put WiFi to sleep". I have tried getting the latest drivers and tried rolling back to previous versions. As a last resort, I tried resetting my laptop too. I am running 20H2 version of Windows 10 and the WiFi driver is Realtek 8822BE Wireless LAN 802.11ac PCI-E NIC. Is this a bug or is there a way to solve this issue? Any help is appreciated.

PS: This is not an issue with the ISP or my router. Streaming works fine in my phone, iPad and TV.
PPS: I booted Ubuntu from a pen drive to check out my WLAN card and the streaming worked fine there. I believe it has got to do with the drivers of Windows 10, but do not know what. :(